# Connecting to remote service to test RPC program

Tags: linux, port, rcp

I am working in a Linux Debian 7 distribution.
I programmed a very simple procedure to test onc-rpc.
The 'remote' call works fine when I call it this way:

```
test_client localhost
```

However, when I invoke it by calling a remote server IP:

```
test_client 202.170.91.155
```

I get an error message:

> 202.170.91.155: RPC: Port mapper failure - RPC: Unable to receive

I am just learning and I know almost nothing about portmapping in Linux.
The IP I was trying to call for the service is the IP address of the same machine. I speculate the rpcbind daemon does the necessary mapping for the server when you register a new service, but I really have no clue.

Which steps should I take in order to fix this error?

Comment: Thanks, for the editing. I hope I get some light into the question because I suspect it's not something about rpc but something more basic regarding networking.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the issue has nothing to do with programming.

This kind of error may appear when the rpcbind daemon (In charge on giving information about the port where the requested service is listening) does not give a response to the calling machine.

This can happen due to errors in NAT or firewalling.
So, a first attempt to diagnose the problema, as with anything regarding networking, could involve verifying the connection is fine by making ping to every interface involved, from closest to furthest, making sure each jump works fine.

For instance, in the issue decribed above: Pinging the supposed internal server ip address (it failed) helped to discover that the machine was using an IP other than the intended (the one mapped to receive request to port 111).

Stopping and restarting eth0 configuration with ifdown/ifup correctly updated ipv4 info, effectively making reachable the rpc service.